# Auto Height of absolute Positioning in css

Tags: html, css

I want to set the image as a background in a div so that the source can be changed for each device for its image resolution. the problem is I don't want to set the height of the div, but only it's width which is 100% so that it can be fit with the device window's width. Therefore, I want the height is automatically generated based on the width of the div.

I have set the height of auto, but the div is not appear unless I set the height with value.

```css
#imagetree {
   position:absolute; 
   z-index:12; 
   width:100%;
   height:auto;
   bottom:0;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: url(images/trees.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: could you add a JSfiddle? this is hard to understand if we don't see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you knew in advance the ratio between width and height of your image you could cheat using a proportional `padding-bottom`

E.g If your image were `300x180` you may use this css

```
#imagetree {
   position:absolute; 
   z-index:1; 
   bottom:0;
   overflow: hidden;
   background: url(http://dummyimage.com/300x180/000000/fff.jpg);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;

   width: 100%;            /* use 100% of width */
   padding-bottom: 60%;    /* 180px is 60% of 300px */
   background-size: cover; /* cover the div entirely with the background */
}
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ruBFt

Comment: That's great! But what is the role of padding-bottom there? I am confused.

Comment: you need to use it in order to ensure that the correct image ratio is preserved. Of course the value I've set it was chosen due to the specific image size I've used. Yours may differ.

Answer (score 1):

When you give `position: absolute`, the `height` and `width` are not set initially. You need to manually set them using CSS. In your case, since you have put background as an image, being positioned absolutely, why do you wanna set it as `background-image`?

You can put the image in the `<img />` tag itself and then render with normal `width`s and `height`s that are proportional to the image too! Change your code by adding an image inside the `absolute`ly positioned container.

```
<div id="imagetree">
    <img src="images/trees.png" />
</div>
```

And in the CSS, you may wanna give this:

```css
#imagetree img {max-width: 100%;}
```

Comment: The reason I use background image is because the source will be changed based on the css query i.e desktop, tablet, phone.

Comment: @AlKush Are all the image of same size? Since you gave the question with **can't**, this makes the answer obsolete.

Comment: No, they have different resolutions or sizes, that's why I use background image. i am sorry about the typo.